# How to add a line of text to multiple files in a directory

Tags: unix, aix

i need to add a line of text at the begininng of each file (commands text) in a directoy (not all of them).

is there any way to do so ?

the line would be something like ID DATE NAME  with spaces inbetween for example : a12345 20190418 tarik

(the files do not contain .txt at the end names are more like .abcd_1452a)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use script like this (file `oneline_file` contain the line you want to add) :

```
echo "a12345 20190418 tarik">oneline_file
for i in *.abcd_1452
do
cat oneline_file "$i" >/tmp/"$i"
mv /tmp/"$i" "$i"
done
```

Comment: the line would be something like ID DATE NAME  with spaces inbetween for example : (the files do not contain .txt at the end names are more like .abcd_1452a)
a12345 20190418 romeo so the script would be :

for i in *.txt
do
cat a12345 20190418 romeo "$i" >/tmp/"$i"
mv /tmp/"$i" "$i"
done

Comment: @TarikMESSAOUDI The pattern `*.txt` is only an example, of course you can use a pattern that matches your files, e.g. `.abcd_*`. You would have to write the data you want as the first line to a file before running the `for` loop. Again `oneline_file` is an example, so you could do something like `echo "a12345 20190418 tarik" > oneline_file`. If you want a better answer you have to add all relevant details to your question.

Comment: @TarikMESSAOUDI, as already mentioned by Bodo this is just example. Check improved version (I edit my answer)

Comment: @RomeoNinov didn't work ... it did create a new file (onelinefile) but the line wasn't added to the other files

Comment: @TarikMESSAOUDI ,execute your script with `bash -x` to see a bit of debug information

Comment: @RomeoNinov

# bash -x s.sh
+ echo 'ld04804 20191231 TARIK'
+ for i in '*file'
+ cat oneline_file oneline_file
+ mv /tmp/oneline_file oneline_file
#

Comment: @TarikMESSAOUDI you have somewhere mistake. Add the script and this log in your question